# Add items to empty list using jQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql, json

I have a function to get items from the database, I can see the items returned in JSON format using the developer tools in the browser. However, nothing gets added to the list.

So I have a list in HTML:

```
<ul id="userCertifications"></ul>
```

Function to get the items from MySQL database:

```
function GetCertifications() {
       $("#userCertifications").empty();
       var userId = $('#userId').val();
       console.log("Current user Id to get certs " + userId);
       $.getJSON('json_data.php', { method: 'getCertifications', userId: userId }, function(data) {
          console.log("User's Certifications >>> " + data);
          $.each(data, function(key, value) {
             console.log("User's Certifications >>> " + value);
             $("#userCertifications").append('<li>' + "Hello World" + '</li>');
          });
       });
    }
```

I am getting JSON data back from the database, however I never reach the line `console.log("User's Certifications >>> " + value);`, so what is wrong with the `$.getJSON` function. How do I get the list to add items from the `$.getJSON` function?

http://screencast.com/t/tbzzKdFM

The response looks like this:

```
[{"rec_id":"81","user_id":"jkittell","certName":"Microsoft SQL - MCITP  ","certExp":null,"lastRecupdate":null},{"rec_id":"80","user_id":"jkittell","certName":"Java SE Programmer 7  ","certExp":null,"lastRecupdate":null},{"rec_id":"79","user_id":"jkittell","certName":"CCIE Service Provider","certExp":null,"lastRecupdate":null},{"rec_id":"78","user_id":"jkittell","certName":"CCNA Voice","certExp":null,"lastRecupdate":null},{"rec_id":"77","user_id":"jkittell","certName":"CCNP Cloud","certExp":null,"lastRecupdate":null},{"rec_id":"76","user_id":"jkittell","certName":"CCNP Collaboration","certExp":null,"lastRecupdate":null},{"rec_id":"75","user_id":"jkittell","certName":"CCNA Service Provider ","certExp":null,"lastRecupdate":null},{"rec_id":"73","user_id":"jkittell","certName":"CCENT","certExp":null,"lastRecupdate":null},{"rec_id":"74","user_id":"jkittell","certName":"CCNA Cloud","certExp":null,"lastRecupdate":null}]
```

Comment: Show the `data` response format. How does it look?

Comment: Make sure the Object you are appending to the function doesn't contain any errors and doublecheck the url :)

Comment: @Isuckatprogramming I put a link to a screenshot of the JSON response, are you asking what the formatted JSON response looks like?

Comment: Of course, it does not do anything since the response is not a valid JSON format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to work you have to remove the

```
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($query);
echo "</pre>";
```

This is preventing your response from begin a valid JSON format. Because what comes after this variable dump is a well formatted JSON.

Comment: Yep, that did it, I was trying to debug the query and see it, looks like that interfered with the JSON response. You nailed it on the head. Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. If it was the correct answer, then I', going to ask you to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

while you write

```
<pre>.../</pre>
```

in yout json file it does not return json array or even json object! what it returns is any thing except json type!
so as remove pre tags and then run your code, it should works properly.